# Extending NextJS's middleware timeout

Tags: next.js, vercel

I am fairly experienced with Node, Express, and React but new to Next.

- I am using Next's middleware to re-write API requests to my backend server (using NextResponse.rewrite).
- I am not using Next's API functionality.
- I am planning to deploy the app to Vercel.

Some of my APIs need more than 60 seconds to respond. From [Vercel's Limits Doc](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/limits/overview#edge-middleware-and-edge-functions-execution-timeout), I see that the middleware function timeout is 30 seconds. Does it apply to rewritten requests (proxied to the backend) as well? If yes, is there a way to extend this? Without it, a Vercel deployment is out of the question and I will have to self-host Next which involves a lot more infra management.